# Axis with JSXGraph

Tags: numbers, axis, jsxgraph

How can I create on a JSXGraph board without a grid an axis without ticks but with some specific numbers (e.g. 25, 50, 75. etc.) on the axis?

I think I've tried everything on this page about axes, ticks and grids:
https://www.intmath.com/cg3/jsxgraph-axes-ticks-grids.php

I can now set the direction of the axis, severel things with ticks or the grid. But I still can't manage the numbers on the axis.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all tick lines on the axis should be suppressed, but the ticks labels should be visible, then the following code can be used:

```js
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], 
    axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
        x: {
        ticks: {
          visible: false,
          label: {visible: true}
        }
      },
        y: {
        ticks: {
          visible: false,
          label: {visible: true}
        }
      }
    }
});
```

With the `board.create('ticks', ...)` command, ticks can be positioned at some special positions by supplying an array with the positions. Again, the tick lines can be set to be invisible so that only labels are shown. Here is an example:

```js
board.create('ticks', [board.defaultAxes.x, [1.5, 2.5]], {
  drawLabels: true,
  visible: false,
  // majorHeight: 10,
  label: {visible: true, anchorX: 'middle', anchorY: 'top', offset: [0, -10]}
});
```

If in addition the label values should be scaled by some factor, then the attribute `scale` comes in handy:

```js
board.create('ticks', [board.defaultAxes.x, [-1.5, -2.5]], {
  drawLabels: true,
  visible: false,
  scale: 1/10,
  label: {visible: true, anchorX: 'middle', anchorY: 'top', offset: [0, -10]}
});
```

If you need even more flexibility it is probably better to place text elements close to the axis.

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/mr0n43t7/.

Comment: Thank you very much, this already helps a lot!
Based on the linked jsfiddle, another question about my understanding: Assuming I only want the labels with the odd values (i.e. 1 and 3) on the positive y-axis. The labels with the even values (i.e. 2 and 4) should be hidden. Is there a simple way to do this?